# How to reload in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile app in ionic framework. I have integrated the login and logout functionality. When I logout it does not logout. When I refresh page then user logout. Here is my code:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    alert("here");
    storageService.clearAll();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();   
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });    
    $scope.popover.hide();
    $state.go('services', {}, {reload: true})   
}
```

Comment: is there any back-end service in your app

Comment: Yes.............@Ahmer

Comment: doing refresh will be a bad solution for that. You should your exact problem. What do you mean by exaclt `not loging out`? is it not going to `services` page after logout?

Comment: did you try $deleget

Comment: It will go service page but my header icons are not changed. after refresh then icons changed

Answer (score 0):

To reload the current URL in your app you could simply invoke this function:

```
document.location.reload()
```

However, as mentioned in your comments by @mudasser-ajaz it might be bad practice, as you should pin point down the cause of your state not showing the user being logged out.

Comment: While this probably is a perfectly good answer, please consider explaining why and how it works.